# A problem of using CURL (with C++) with GET method from Twitter API

Tags: c++, curl, twitter

Recently I'm into using CURL with the Twitter API, unfortunately my code isn't working (for now).

It was engineered to send `GET` requests to Twitter APIs and write received content to a file. Some code came from the Internet, I don't remember its source.

The code is working with HTTP, but all Twitter APIs use HTTPS, that's why I can't use it anymore. It's compiling and linking properly.

Here's a screenshot of the app describing the problem:

[image]

EDIT: I cut off the `Bearer` token due to safety.

EDIT: Sorry for not properly describing the problem, currently I'm new here.

```
size_t curl_tech_writeRequestFile(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream)
{
    size_t writtenData = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return writtenData;
}

void getFromTwitterToFile(std::string statusNumber)
{
    std::string bearerToken = ""; //secret!
    std::string data;
    std::string fullBearer = "Authorization: Bearer " + bearerToken;
    std::string tempFile = userSettings.tempFilePath + "temp.dat";
    std::string api_url = 
        "http://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/" 
        + statusNumber
        + "?tweet.fields=attachments,author_id,created_at,entities,id,text&media.fields=preview_image_url,url&expansions=attachments.media_keys";

    std::cout << api_url << std::endl;

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode res;
    FILE* fp;
    
    //checking if curl initialised properly
    if (!curl)
    {
        std::cout << "Curl hasn't initialised properly" << std::endl;
    }

    //opening a file
    fp = fopen(tempFile.c_str(), "wb");

    //setting up api url
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, api_url.c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    //file 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_tech_writeRequestFile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, fullBearer.c_str());

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BEARER);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER, bearerToken);

    //performing 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Error in performing CURL action" << std::endl;
        std::cout << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
    }

    //cleanup
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain what the **actual problem** is. You just dumped your code here without any explanation of what it is trying to do, or what is not working with it. Please elaborate.

Comment: Reedited, thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

> The code is working with HTTP, but all Twitter APIs use HTTPS, that's why I can't use it anymore

libcurl supports both HTTP and HTTPS. The real problem is that when you are sending your HTTP request, the server is **redirecting** you to an HTTPS url.  libcurl can follow that redirect automatically for you, but only if you enable the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html) option, which is disabled by default.

Though, you really should update your code to send requests to HTTPS urls to begin with, especially knowing that the Twitter API uses HTTPS.